# git rebase -i, and clean commits

Tags: git, merge, rebase

I'm learning git, coming from having used CVS a while ago ... Here's a situation I ran into, if anyone has any hints on how to learn about this.

I created a branch for a bugfix (bug435). I made 4 commits and then pushed to github (which we use for our centralized repository). I saw the PR (still learning the PR process), and saw that the diff it generated was very messy, and the reviewer would have to wade through line-by-line, (in this case, creating one new function, that I tweaked over several commits). I'd prefer it to look like only one addition, with the entire function in one piece.

So I tried 'git rebase -i HEAD~4' (there were 4 commits), and specified the commits to squash. That seemed to work and 'git log' on my local repository was modified. But on the remote repository (on github itself), the change history didn't reflect my rebase. So I reasoned that I needed to do a 'git push'. 'git push' gave me a message saying, I needed a  'git pull' so I did this. But -- this generated a merge, which surprised me.

Still wondering about the merge, I went ahead with the 'git push'. I checked the branch history for bug345 on github and all looked nice -- which I thought was great news, the rebase worked! I created a new PR -- but instead they contained my original commits, a merge commit, and two new commits from my rebase. It generated 3 extra commits :) Not what I was expecting.

My reasoning throughout this -- I believed I could do a rebase, basically change the branch HEAD pointer back to where my first change was, apply the changes in one commit (rewriting history), and push this branch to the remote repo, which would reflect only the rebased changes. But what I didn't anticipate was that there was a merge (one extra commit) and that the remote repo branch still "remembered" my old commits.

Any pointers or hints as to what's happening under the scenes? :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You are only rewriting your own history. The remote history is different.

A git pull will fetch the remote changes and try to merge, by definition.

You have to get the remote repository to forget the history or accept it being rewritten as well, for example using the -f (force) option. Or simply delete the old PR and make a new one with a proper history.